# Unable to access td “colindex” attribute with locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, locker-service

I am facing an issue with the Locker Service. I have a simple piece of code. I have attached the code here. The issue is that if the Locker Service is deactivated, I am able to get the value using “colindex” attribute the element output is as shown in the screenshot. Whereas, if it is activated, I am unable to get the value using “colindex” attribute. I have attached both screenshots as well as the code.

**Spring 17 - Salesforce**

DemoTestApp.app

```
<aura:application >
   <c:testJqueryComponent />
</aura:application >
```

DemoTest.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js')}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded='{!c.doResult}'/>
<div id="divTest"></div>
<br/>
<h1 id="pvalue" style="font-size:20px;"></h1>
</aura:component>
```

DemoTestController.js

```
({
doResult : function(component, event, helper) {
    $("#divTest").html('<table><tr>'
                       +'<td colindex="1" >value 1</td>'
                       +'<td colindex="2" >value 2</td>'
                       +'</tr></table>');
    $('#pvalue').html('first td colindex value: '+$('tr td:first').attr('colindex'));
}
})
```

Elements output: Locker service is deactivated[image]

Elements output: Locker service is activated
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLTableDataCellElement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td does not appear to support colindex (or colIndex) and locker has a very specific whitelist for attributes, methods, classes, etc that are supported based on standards specifications.

Doing a quick google search also yields very few hits on support for colindex in browsers.

*HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex* and *HTMLTableCellElement.cellIndex* do exist and are already supported in locker.

Custom attributes are also fully supported, e.g. data-colindex